# htaccess redirect old index.php with extensions to new url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having some trouble redirecting these links properly through htaccess.

Website use to be dynamic, and is now static.

This page does not exist anymore, but there are still links out there that reference the page through these url's, so I need them redirected.

http://www.example.com/?en=about

and

http://www.example.com/index.php/?en=about

They should be redirected to a new static html page recently created.

What is the best way to go about this through htacess? I've tried some rewrites, but not working. Any help would be appreciated - thanks

Comment: What is the name of new html page ?

Comment: https://www.example.com/about-us.html

Comment: How redirect must know that en=about is redirected to about-us ?

Comment: I have tried some rewrites. but not working- can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I don't quite understand? The old site was built using a php framework. The 2 urls I posted above brought users to the OLD 'about' page. That page no longer exists, but there are still links online that point to that page. I'm trying to redirect or rewrite those urls to the NEW about page. https://www.example.com/about-us.html

Comment: Look my answer, may be it is you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggested that the file name matches the value en

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^en=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(index.php/|)$ /%1.html? [R,L]
```

If only one page - about-us, then code below

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^en=about
RewriteRule ^(index.php/|)$ /about-us.html? [R,L]
```

Comment: okay, using the 2nd example for only one page - the redirect is working properly coming from...  http://www.example.com/?en=about but... i still get a 404 when coming from http://www.example.com/index.php/?en=about

Comment: @ADP  Sorry, lost trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to 301 for permanent redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /old.php /new.php
```

So in your case you would want something like:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/?en=about /about.php
```

Comment: I have tried using 301 the same way as  your example. It gives me a 404 and does not redirect